# Big cup: Scale other symbols in displaymath to cup size

Tags: math-mode

I have the following code:

```
\[ \Sigma \setminus \bigcup_{(s,s') \in \mathit{matched}_{\sigma,\sigma'}} s \cap s' \]
```

that produces this output:

[image]

However, I want the sigma and backslash to be scaled to the size of the big union symbol. Is this possible?

Comment: For a larger backslash, I don't think `\Big` will work, but `\text{\Large$\setminus$}` should be a start in the desired direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without addressing the appropriateness of it, one can use `\scalerel*` to make the first two symbols scale to the same vertical footprint as `\bigcup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \scalerel*{\Sigma \setminus}{\bigcup} \bigcup_{(s,s') \in \mathit{matched}_{\sigma,\sigma'}} s \cap s' \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason for making `\Sigma` bigger.

You can enlarge the set difference symbol using the fact that `\backslash` is a growing delimiter.

An alternative would be to make `\bigcup` smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\Sigma \mathbin{\Big\backslash}
\bigcup_{(s,s') \in \mathrm{matched}_{\sigma,\sigma'}} s \cap s'
\]

\[
\textstyle
\Sigma \mathbin{\big\backslash}
\bigcup\limits_{(s,s') \in \mathrm{matched}_{\sigma,\sigma'}} s \cap s'
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]